# can a function parameter own a method in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable

I am trying to understand the observables RxJs and I am using angular framework! I can't understand what is actually happening in 'subscriber function' ,it has a parameter named 'observer', and this parameter has a method in the function body, and its name is next()!can a function parameter own a method? based on which rule?!
and the next question is : what is happening in the 'Observable' class? I think the subscriber function returns or to be more precise, creates and passes a value to the Observable instance! and when we call the subscribe method on 'customIntervalObservable' , it passes that data or value to the subscribe method?
am I right?

```
const customIntervalObservable = new Observable(function subscriber(
  observer
) {
  let count = 0;
  setInterval(() => {
    count++;
    observer.next(+count);
    if (count > 3) {
      observer.error(new Error("count is greater than 3"));
    }
  }, 1000);
});
this.firstObjSubs = customIntervalObservable.subscribe(
  (data: number) => {
    console.log(data);
  },
  (error) => {
    console.log(error), alert(error.message);
  }
);
```

}

```
 ngOnDestroy() {
    //this.firstObjSubs.unsubscribe();
    this.firstObjSubs.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a bit more:

You can think of an Observer as something that watches the Observable and reacts to notifications.

[image]

What notifications?

- Next: When another item is emitted into the Observable
- Error: When an error occurs
- Complete: When there are no more items to emit

[image]

`Observer` is an object with three functions: one for each type of notification. You can define an Observer in code as shown below. But this is uncommon.

[image]

And then pass that Observer object into the subscribe as shown below:

[image]

More often, you'll pass *either* the next callback as shown in the first example below. Or an object with one, two, or three of the callback functions defined as shown in the second example.

[image]

The subscribe method tells the Observable stream to start emitting its values. It does *not* itself emit any values. Think of it as a streaming service, like Disney+ or hulu. You have to first subscribe to the service before you can stream movies.

Does this help?

Comment: Great! Can you mark this as your answer to close the question? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

*can a function parameter own a method?*

Javascript functions parameters are not typed, so you can pass any value you want - including an object.

*what is happening in the 'Observable' class?*

I'll give this a try:

- An `observable` is basically just a wrapper around a - `subscribe()` - function that essentially describes the logic of the `observable` behaviour.
- An `observable` has the ability to notify `subjects` - or `subscribers`, or `observers` - of changes occuring in its state during its lifecycle. To do so, a contract exists that states that the `observable` should call a `subject` `next()` method. This method should describe the logic for how the `subject` wants to react to such changes.
- When a `subject` is interested in being notified by an `observable` of its state changes, it executes the `observable` `subscribe()` method, passing itself to it as an argument. This effectively provides the `observable` the ability to call the `subject` `next()` method whenever its logic dictates to do so.

To basically illustrate this in code:

```
// Function describing the observable logic.
function subscribe(observer){
  // Observable logic, including calling observer.next() as many times as the logic dictates to notify the observer of state changes.
}
// Observable wrapper.
let observable = new Observable(subscribe)
// Subject interested in being notified of the observable state changes.
let observer = {
    next(value){
        // Logic for how to react to notifications from the observable.
    }
}
// Effectively execute the observable logic.
observable.subscribe(observer)
```

For simplicty's sake, I omitted a number of more minor concepts - such as the `subject` `complete()` or `error()` methods, as well as the `unsubscribe()` function returned by the `observable` `subscribe()` function.